# how to do it and what's the meaning in magento?

Tags: magento

Sometime we need to display webstore categories with there images on homepage, its very simple to do it
just create a page call it `hopepage.phtml` then go to magento backend and call cms block.

i don't know how to do "`call cms block.` thank you

Comment: play with the insert widget button on the content tab of the CMS page.

Comment: when i click the  insert widget button there is no widget of my template---homepage.html. why?

Comment: if homepage is a CMS Page, then look for CMS Page widget. If it is a CMS block, them it would be in CMS Block widget

Answer (score 0):

Why not have the images/category listing generate automatically?

Layout XML for your page:

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="core/template" name="main.search" as="mainSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"/>
<block type="catalog/navigation" name="home.catalog.category.list" as="home_catalog_category_list" template="catalog/category/list.phtml" after="cms_page" />
</reference>
```

Your theme should have the following file in `./template/catalog/category/list.phtml`

```
<?php $_categories = $this->getStoreCategories(); ?>
<?php $_count = is_array($_categories)?count($_categories):$_categories->count(); ?>
<?php if($_count): ?>
<div class="category-list-main">
    <ul>
    <?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
        <?php if($_category->getIsActive()): ?>
        <li class="main-category">
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category); ?>">
                <?php
                    if ($category_image_url = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setData($_category->getData())->load($_category->getId())->getThumbnail()):
                ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'.$category_image_url; ?>">
                <?php
                    endif;
                ?>
                <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()); ?>
            </a>
        </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```